# How can I reference my class PID to my main?

Tags: c++

this is my files which I cut, but the essential is there

I have my file PID.h:

```
#ifndef PID_H_
#define PID_H_

class PID
{
    public:
        PID();
}
```

And my PID.cpp file:

```
#include "PID.h"

PID::PID(){

}
```

And my main.cpp:

```
#include "PID.h"
PID pid;

void setup(){}
void loop() {}
```

I'm wondering why I have this mistake:

```
C:\...\ccevwRea.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_stairs':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x98): undefined reference to `PID::PID()'
```

Thanks !

Comment: Because you need to compile not only `main.cpp` but also `PID.cpp`. And add both objects (`.o`) to the linker command.

Comment: Ripl2's probably right, but Alex, you can nail this down by adding the command line instructions used to build the program.